# Download the attachments of the mail based on keywords in subject

Tags: node.js, email, express

I need to make a node js progame which could download the attachments of the incoming mails. The programe should only download the attachments of the emails with certain given keywords in subject.

example :- If the keyword is 'student' then the incoming email which has the keyword student in its subject should be selected and all the attachments of that email should be downloaded.

I want to know what could be the best tool or way to implement such functionality in nodejs. Is there any API or node module which could make this process simple ?

Comment: Which email-service are you using? are you using gmail?

Comment: i am using outlook email - service

Comment: Outlook provides some API's to access mail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started

Comment: If you are having gmail account on outlook then you can do all actions as per your requirement using gmail api https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/